# Preload or not preload?

Tags: swift, performance, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm making a puzzle game, where I use few types of sprites many times. So I have a question about the game performance. Which is better, to create the sprite in `for/in` loop later in `setup()` method, or to preload the sprite in initializer of class, and then just copy the sprite in `setup()`? For example:

```
func setup() {
    for i in 0...10 {
       let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "FirstSpriteName")
       sprite.position = etc...
    }
}
```

or preload the sprite when I initialize the class:

```
let firstSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "FirstSpriteName")
```

and later in the `setup()` func:

```
func setup() {
    for i in 0...10 {
        let sprite = firstSprite.copy()
        sprite.position = etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the same image multiple times it is better to load it like this:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "SpriteName")
```

then later use it whenever you need:

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
```

this way it only loads the texture once however many sprites use it.

Comment: I did it this way, created a `struct` with `static let` SKTexture references for all my sprites, and in `for/in` loop get it from this struct. Is my decision is good?

Comment: That will work for preloading. Good luck with the game :)